# How to PassOptionsToPackage from inside a quarto document?

Tags: python, latex, r-markdown, quarto

Consider the following `quarto` document:

```
---
title: "Some title"
author: X
date: "2022"
format: 
  pdf:
   number-sections: true
   fontsize: 12 pt
   papersize: A4
   fig-pos: 'H'
   geometry: "left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm"
   include-in-header:
     text: |
       \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
       \usepackage{float}
       \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

engine: jupyter
jupyter: r-reticulate
---

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
\cellcolor{blue} 3 & \cellcolor{red} 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I get the following error, when rendering it:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.83 \KOMAoption
                {captions}{tableheading}
```

A solution that works is to add `table` to the following line of the `tex` file generated by `quarto`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
```

That is:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names, table}{xcolor}
```

My question is: How can I do that from inside the `quarto` document instead of hacking the `tex` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83102/261065) on *Tex StackExchange*, one possible solution could be passing `table` as a `classoption` and you do not need to declare using `xcolor` explicitly since it is used by-default.

```
---
title: "Some title"
author: X
date: "2022"
format: 
  pdf:
   number-sections: true
   fontsize: 12 pt
   papersize: A4
   fig-pos: 'H'
   geometry: "left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm"
   classoption: table
   include-in-header:
     text: |
       \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
       \usepackage{float}
---

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\hline 
\cellcolor{blue} 3 & \cellcolor{red} 4\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

---

[image: renderd pdf output]

---

Comment: Thanks a lot, @shafee: Once again, you were my savior! Your solution works like a charm!